# returning PNG image from php script recognized as document

Tags: php, image, content-type

How can I return an image from a php file? I have the `image.php` with this code:

```
<?php
$im = imagecreatefrompng("myImage.png");
header("Content-Type: image/png");
?>
```

But actually entering `domain.com/image.php` it is to recognized as `document` by the browser, and not as an image... and returns an empty result

Comment: Enable error_reporting, and your code doesn't return any data (`imagecreatefrom..` alone just instantiates a GD resouce).

Answer (score 1):

Well, you have to output the image, making sure to send the headers first:

```
header("Content-type: image/png");
$im = imagecreatefrompng("myImage.png");
imagepng($im);
```

`myImage.png` needs to be in the same directory as `image.php` or else you need to specify the path to the image.

But if you're not doing anything other than outputting, just:

```
header("Content-type: image/png");
readfile("myImage.png");
```

Comment: Enabled error reporting as @mario suggested?  "Not working" is not very descriptive.

Comment: Ahh, maybe look at Content-disposition?  `header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename= "myfile.png");`